# Display data vertically in ListView

Tags: android, listview, vertical-scrolling

I have created an android application in that I want to display some Image data vertically in ListView.

How to make it possible ?

I tried using this code-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="360dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:entries="@array/country_image_list" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: image data vertically means.....?can you tell that clearly?

Comment: means Images are vertically scrolled in Listview.

Comment: `HorizontalScrollView` will suit your requirement.

Comment: yes please elaborate more on the question and if you have tried some code then post that too....

Comment: Hello @ManishDubey do you have any example ?

Comment: @AnjaliPandya Check [this one](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/)

Comment: @AnjaliPandya following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) you will be able to create your customized list view...

Comment: why not you can do it vertically or horizontally.....!

Comment: can you post screen shot that you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ItemImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> paths;
private ImageLoader iml;

public ItemImagesAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<String> image_paths) {
    context = activity;
    paths = image_paths;
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(activity).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    iml = ImageLoader.getInstance();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return paths.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return paths.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_image, parent, false);
    }
    String path = paths.get(position);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image1);
    iml.displayImage(path, image);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

take one more layout for list item as R.layout.list_item_image.
here i am taking image loader to load the images from server.
if you are getting images by means local...then set them directly

hope this may helps you

Comment: How this adapter source code matches OP requirement? It is basic code of adapter for any listview.

Comment: refer her comment in the question ...i asked her requirment..then the reply was this.."means Images are vertically scrolled in Listview."....
am i wrong...if yes kindly correct me..

Comment: Where is code of horizontal scrolling in listview in above adapter code? It is just basic adapter code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manage your requirement using [TwoWayView](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) for Horizontal scrolling of ListView items with Vertical scrolling. You can aslo check [this](https://github.com/lalit3686/VerticalHorizontalListView) demo for the same on github.

Answer (score 0):

**XML for first activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FirstActivity" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView 
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**XML for row layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >


    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />


</LinearLayout>
```

Create this layouts and then using custom adapter class you can fill the images for each row in image view...Something like this

**Custom Adapter class**

```
public class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
Activity activity;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public customAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> al) {
    Log.e("check", "");
    activity = a;
    this.al = al;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return al.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
    }
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.myImage);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(//your image from resource here),myImage);
    return vi;
}

}
```

Any problem in this you can follow the link of the tutorial I have mentioned in the comments...